# Ограничение на IP: выполнение скрипта пользователем с каким-то IP не более 1 раза в 30 секунд

Tags: php

Допустим, на сайт пришел пользователь и воспользовался скриптом поиска по сайту, как сделать ограничение на использование этого скрипта с помощью PHP? Т.е. чтобы при повторном выполнении скрипта, если не прошло 30 секунд, ему бы выдавалось сообщение: подождите немного.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создать таблицу с request. В которой хранить IP, и время последнего посещения. Извлекаем IP из $_SERVER. Ищем в таблице, если нет такого дописываем, если есть сравниваем время последнего request с текущим, что то наподобие этого

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, time_request, NOW())
```

Если время не превышает интервал обновляем поле с временем последнего request, в противном случае выдаем сообщение об ошибке.

Answer (score 2):

Если не критично, то лучше кукой назначать сессию на 30 секунд, чтобы не создавать еще одну помойку на хостинге. А там уже JSом проверять, чтобы нагрузку не создавать.
Про куки тут, например: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php

а вот как javascript прочитать куку уже было на хэше: http://hashcode.ru/questions/7484/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-javascript-%D0%B8-jquery

Comment: Если используются куки, то их легко и затереть.

Answer (score 1):

Мой вариант:

Описание данных:

```
cookie = {
 time,        //Время прошлого успешного запроса
 md5_time     //md5( time + salt )
}

//Некий объект, допустим memcached
//Для каждого ip - timestamp десяти последних визитов без cookie
mem_ip = {
  ip1: [ time1, time2, time3 ]    
};

//Некий объект, допустим memcached
//timestamp тысячи последних визитов без cookie
mem_all = [ time1, time2, time3 ];
```

Алгоритм

```
Если кука есть и она верная
Тогда
  Если ( curr_time - cookie.time ) > 30
  Тогда:
    Обновляем куку
    Пропускаем запрос
  Иначе:
    Блокируем запрос
Иначе
  //Проверка на DoS
  Если count( mem_all, time > curr_time - 60 ) > 100
  Тогда:
    Блокируем запрос
  //Защита от очистки куки, но небольшая поблажка для NAT
  Если count( mem_ip[ req_ip ], time > curr_time - 60 ) > 3
  Тогда:
    mem_all.push( curr_time );
    mem_ip[ req_ip ].push( curr_time );
    Блокируем запрос
  Иначе:
    Создаём куку
    Пропускаем запрос
```

Comment: Тот же memcached (для незнакомых с оным) заменить на БД (как в ответе @alter_f4), отличный ответ

Comment: memcached побыстрее чем БД ))

Comment: Не спорю, поэтому и говорю, что для незнакомых с ним

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант :

1. Создавать файл с именем содержащим его ip адрес в md5 и форматом txt.
2. Проверять время создания данного файла, и если со времени создания прошло больше 30 секунд, то разрешить, иначе запретить.

В принципе самый простой и быстрый способ.

Вот код :

```
<?php
$f_name     =   './gts/'.md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']).'txt';
#
if (file_exists($f_name) && (microtime(true) - filemtime($f_name) < 30) ) {
    echo '30 секунд не прошло, подождите немного и повторите попытку.';
} else {
    $fp     =   fopen($f_name, 'w');
    fclose($fp);
    #
    //нужный вам код 
    echo 'Можно пользоваться)';
}
?>
```

Не забудьте создать папку gts - в ней будут создаваться файлы.

Comment: вы представляете сколько там будет лежать файлов при хотя бы средней нагрузке?

Comment: быстрый? вы знаете что самое узкое место - это работа с ФС?)))

Answer (score 0):

Поддерживаю вариант с куками и сессией, просто писать в куки время последнего запроса, и потом сравнивать либо через JS либо уже на сервере. Этот вариант лучше как минимум по двум причинам:

1. Не нужно хранить кучу лишней информации на сервере.
2. Несколько пользователей выходящих с разных машин, но через один шлюз (имеющих один внешний IP) не будут мешать друг другу.